# ELAN Touchpad not working on Lenovo Thinkbook with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kernel, touchpad, lenovo

I bought a Lenovo Thinkbook (Intel i5 10th generation) just last week. I installed ubuntu 18.04. The touchpad hasnt been working ever since. I have not checked it on Windows, as I bought a DOS machine and put ubuntu on it,

Kernel is 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu.

I have followed links from here:
[Lenovo IdeaPad 330 touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working) and https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/ which talk about upgrading firmware. When I did "sudo fwupdmgr update", nothing showed up.

I also see that one of the above links asks to modify kernel, but I am not sure thats the right thing to do as I have a kernel which is beyond  4.18. The link also claims that Ubuntu 18.04 should not have this problem. But, I have this problem.

When I do a sudo acpidump | grep -C3 ELAN, I get the following

```
33230: 0F 00 03 04 49 4E 54 31 70 0A 20 49 44 41 44 A4  ....INT1p. IDAD.
 33240: 84 53 42 46 53 53 42 46 49 00 5B 82 4D 0D 54 50  .SBFSSBFI.[.M.TP
 33250: 44 32 08 5F 41 44 52 00 08 49 44 41 44 00 08 48  D2._ADR..IDAD..H
 33260: 49 44 32 00 08 5F 48 49 44 0D 45 4C 41 4E 30 36  ID2.._HID.ELAN06
 33270: 32 46 00 08 5F 43 49 44 0D 50 4E 50 30 43 35 30  2F.._CID.PNP0C50
 33280: 00 08 5F 55 49 44 01 14 46 04 5F 44 53 4D 04 A0  .._UID..F._DSM..
 33290: 37 93 68 11 13 0A 10 F7 F6 DF 3C 67 42 55 45 AD  7.h.......<gBUE
```

When I type in dmesg | grep i2c, I get:

```
[    1.792338] i2c /dev entries driver
```

When I type dmesg | grep elan, I get nothing on the terminal.

I have run out of ideas. I have tried all that I could. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: It may be a simple matter of settings. What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys touchpad-toggle`?

Comment: Strange. It says -No such key “touchpad-toggle”. When I go to "Mouse and Touchpad" settings, I do not see an option for Touchpad. I only see Mouse settings. And when I do: xinput list, I do not see Touchpad listed there.

Comment: Do you run an X session or a Wayland session?

Comment: I am running an X session

Comment: I have the same problem in ubuntu 16.04 (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206190/elan-touchpad-not-working-on-lenovo-ideapad-with-ubuntu-16-04)). It seems that as long as the device id is not added to the kernel, ubuntu will not recognize it! I fear that the only solutions are either to recompile the kernel, or file a bug report and wait for a new kernel that includes the device id to come out.

Comment: @Nanditha, I'm also facing the same problem i.e., touchpad not detected and working on ubuntu 18.04. Is your problem resolved? If so, can you please provide me the fix?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your specific Elan touchpad (Elan 062F) can be fixed by following the steps in [this thread here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277)

The comment which fixes your problem is [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277/comments/15)

This Lenovo machine that I'd purchased also has the same issue, but with a different touchpad model.

Try these steps mentioned in the thread and let me know if it works for you.:

1. Disassemple the current dsdt ACPI table (see [this link](https://01.org/linux-acpi/utilities)):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/acpitables
cd /tmp/acpitables
sudo acpidump > acpidump.out
acpixtract -a acpidump.out
iasl -d dsdt.dat
```

In my case the output dsdt.dsl file contained some invalid error output lines at the very beginning which I just removed. Otherwise, the compiling in step 4 results in errors.

2. Apply this patch to dsdt.dsl (see [this link](https://github.com/realnickel/lenovo_thinkbook_iml15_touchpad_acpi_fix/commit/de0ca637f7d8de2164c787801b4af9d4ff586d67)):

```
- Name (_HID, "XXXX0000") // _HID: Hardware ID
+ Name (_HID, "ELAN062F") // _HID: Hardware ID
```

3. Create an assembler source file out of the patched dsdt.dsl:

```
iasl -sa dsdt.dsl
```

4. Create a CPIO archive to be loaded by the bootloader (see [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT#Using_a_CPIO_archive)):

```
mkdir -p kernel/firmware/acpi
cp dsdt.aml ssdt1.aml kernel/firmware/acpi
find kernel | cpio -H newc --create > acpi_override
sudo cp acpi_override /boot
```

5. Install the patched dsdt file (see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027552/including-a-custom-acpi-dsdt-with-kubuntu-18-04-rc1)):

```
cpio --extract < ./acpi_override
cp kernel/firmware/acpi/dsdt.aml /boot/fixed_dsdt.aml
```

and Create or update `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` to contain
`acpi /fixed_dsdt.aml`

Comment: I followed all steps and on _Apply this patch to dsdt.dsl_. didn't explain on how to apply the patch. is it download the github file and replace the dsdt.dsl or add line or something, or replace XXXX0000 to `ELAN062F`?? because i cant find any `XXXX0000` on generated dsdt.dsl.

also while doing `cp dsdt.aml ssdt1.aml kernel/firmware/acpi` ssdt1.aml was not found.
please elaborate..