# ELAN Touchpad not working on Lenovo IdeaPad with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel, touchpad, lenovo

Recently I bought a Lenovo IdeaPad (Intel i7 10th generation). I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it, but **at no point did the touchpad work for me!** Also, initially I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 and upgraded to the latest kernel, but not only the touchpad didn't work, also the graphics didn't work properly and I eventually decided to go back to 16.04.
I have not checked the touchpad on Windows, as I bought a DOS machine and put ubuntu on it instead.
The touchpad is not the only hardware on my laptop that's not working in ubuntu, but let's focus only on it for now.

From reading a little bit I found out that many new laptops have problems with their touchpads, mostly ElanTech hid ones.
It seems to me that my problem is similar to this post: [ELAN Touchpad not working on Lenovo Thinkbook with Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205382/elan-touchpad-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkbook-with-ubuntu-18-04).

Also, from the information in this post: [Lenovo IdeaPad 330 touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working), it seems the problem is that the id of my ELAN touchpad is not listed in the kernel, so Ubuntu doesn't recognize it at all!

About my system:
`uname -srv` gives:

```
Linux 4.15.0-74-generic #83~16.04.1-Ubuntu
```

`xinput -list` gives:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**Note that no touchpad is recognized by Ubuntu!**
By running `sudo acpidump | grep -C3 -i elan` I was able to find my ELAN id, which is 0633, as seen here:

```
 27AA0: 59 53 0B DC 07 53 52 58 4F 0C 10 00 01 06 01 70  YS...SRXO......p
 27AB0: 47 4E 55 4D 0C 10 00 01 06 49 4E 54 31 70 49 4E  GNUM.....INT1pIN
 27AC0: 55 4D 0C 10 00 01 06 49 4E 54 32 A0 25 93 54 50  UM.....INT2.%.TP
 27AD0: 54 59 01 70 0D 45 4C 41 4E 30 36 33 33 00 5F 48  TY.p.ELAN0633._H
 27AE0: 49 44 70 0A 15 42 41 44 52 70 01 48 49 44 32 A4  IDp..BADRp.HID2.
 27AF0: 00 A0 27 93 54 50 54 59 0A 02 70 0D 53 59 4E 41  ..'.TPTY..p.SYNA
 27B00: 32 42 36 31 00 5F 48 49 44 70 0A 2C 42 41 44 52  2B61._HIDp.,BADR
```

Apparently this problem can be solved by recompiling the kernel with this id code included in the `elan_i2c_core.c` file, but I don't want to mess with the kernel!

Is there any other way I can solve this problem?
If not, I would appreciate some help in filing a bug report.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en describes the process of filing a bug. Wish I could provide a solution.

Comment: What program should I put in `ubuntu-bug nameofprogram`, if this is related to the kernel?

Comment: f you have a hardware issue or don't know the name of the program affected, just type `ubuntu-bug`

Comment: @K7AAY, thanks for the guidance. I did notice the instructions say that if you don't know the program's name, you should just omit it. However, apparently when you need to report kernel problems the right thing to do is to write: `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, eventually I managed to get the touchpad working on Ubuntu 18.04, kernel version: `5.3.0-46-generic` thanks to comments on this link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/f9h0q4/touchpad_issue_lenovo_s14515iil/

Basically what needs to be done is:

1. Open the file `/etc/default/grub` for editing, for example by running

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Add to the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`: `"i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"` so that it reads:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
   ```

   If other parameters are there between the double quotes, it may be OK to leave them.
3. Save the file and exit
4. Run this command to update the GRUB configuration:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm. This works on my Lenovo V14-IIL with ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ideapad3 17IIL05:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

update these lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nocrs"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="initcall_blacklist=elants_i2c_driver_init"
```

Save the file and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: ideapad3 17IIL05

Answer (score 0):

I installed kernel 5.19 on my lenovo 81WE IdeaPad 3 15IIL05 and problem gone

Comment: Installing a custom, mainline kernel might not be the best solution for everybody.