# Problems with Touchpad in ubuntu 20.04 with acpi=off

Tags: boot, touchpad, live-usb, 20.04, acpi

My goal is to update my ubuntu 19.04 system to 20.04 LTS as the support faded out. I have prepared the newer os as a live system on a stick. As I have had problems with this particular hardware configuration of my laptop and linux earlier, I am trying to get the live system up and running before starting the actual installation. Without any changes of grub parameters, the system would not boot at all. With acpi=off it does. However, the touchpad does not work and also shutting down is problematic (which is less of an issue). I tried booting my old 19.04 system with acpi=off as well (even though it works without) for testing purposes. The same issues regarding touchpad and shutdown ensue.
How can I make the touchpad (and ideally also the shutdown) work?

xinput on my old system yields the following information regarding the touchpad:

```
FTCS1000:00 2808:0101 Touchpad              id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

The /proc/bus/input/devices file lists the touchpad in the following way:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=2808 Product=0101 Version=0100
N: Name="FTCS1000:00 2808:0101 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-FTCS1000:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-FTCS1000:00/0018:2808:0101.0001/input/input21
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event15 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

When booting with acpi=off (on either system) both methods will not show any touchpad, so I figure it is not even recognized by the system in this case.
The 19.04 version uses the 4.18.0-25-generic kernel.
20.04 LTS uses the more recent 5.4.0-26-generic kernel.
I have also tried a couple of other common recommended grub parameter changes like e.g. adding noapic, nolapic or nomodeset. None of it seemed to help.
Furthermore I tried creating the installation medium in various ways: with the startup disk creator utility of ubuntu and also from within Windows (10) with both win32 Disk Imager and Rufus in different configurations.
I have not used plain ubuntu in all attempts, as I am ultimately aiming at installing xubuntu. Still, both yielded the same results which seems plausible as I figure the desktop environment probably has nothing to do with this rather low level issue.

Any help is welcome.
Let me know about any additional information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I was/am having a similar problem with a Clevo NL51LU on 20.04. I think it might (also?) be an ELANTECH touchpad. The workaround for me was to add pci=nocrs flag to the kernel boot grub line.
See [ELAN Touchpad not working on Lenovo IdeaPad with Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206190/elan-touchpad-not-working-on-lenovo-ideapad-with-ubuntu-16-04) (the i8042 parameter isn't needed).

There's a kernel bug opened about this, indicating the problem might be in the machine bios, if you are seeing a "failed to claim resource" message in your kernel log - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1884232